# Stack not popping correct values

Tags: c, pointers, stack, memory-address

I cant seem to get my stack to operate as well... a stack. It seems to complie properly, and from what I understand the push and pop functions are written correctly (but they may be wrong).

I attempt to push 2 integers into the stack, and then pop them out again in order to test it, but it pops out what would appear to me to be a memory address in integer form, however this may not be the case. Either way it is not popping the correct value, and I cant find anything obvious with the code.

It may be important to note that the popped values do not seem to change through several iterations, but I think the malloc call would prevent this anyhow.. I am using the GNU GCC compiler included in Code:blocks.

below is the lib.c file:

```
#include "defs.h"
//Initialising the stack
TopStack* initTOS()
{
    TopStack* pTopStack;
    pTopStack = (TopStack*)malloc(sizeof(TopStack));
    return (pTopStack);
}

//Pushing an element onto the stack
void push(TopStack* ts, int val)
{
    if (ts->num == 0) {
        Stack* pNewNode;
        pNewNode = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        pNewNode->val = val;
        pNewNode->next = NULL;
        ts->top = pNewNode;
        ts->num++;
    }
    else if (ts->num != 0) {
        Stack* pNewNode;
        pNewNode = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        pNewNode->val = val;
        pNewNode->next = ts->top;
        ts->top = pNewNode;
        ts->num++;
    }
}

int pop(TopStack* ts)
{
    if (ts->num == 0) {
        printf("Can't pop, stack is empty!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        Stack* pTemp;
        int RemovedValue;
        RemovedValue = pTemp->val;
        ts->top = pTemp->next;
        ts->num--;
        free(pTemp);
        return (RemovedValue);
    }
}

void testStack(TopStack* ts)
{
    int RemovedValue;
    push(ts, 1);
    push(ts, 2);
    printf("the popped value was %i\n", pop(ts));
    printf("the popped value was %i\n", pop(ts));
}
```

the structs are stored here in defs.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_EXPR 50

//struct that contains stack's element

typedef struct stack_elem {
    int val;
    struct stack_elem* next;
} Stack;

//struct that contains the pointer to the top of the stack

typedef struct {
    int num; //num of elements in stack
    Stack* top;
    ; //top of stack
} TopStack;

//ts=pointer to the top of stack, val=element to push

void push(TopStack* ts, int val); //push element on the stack

//prints the elements in the stack

void printStack(TopStack* ts);

// initialize the structure that will point to the top of the stack

TopStack* initTOS();

// a simple test for the stack

void testStack(TopStack* ts);

// ts=pointer to the top of stack

int pop(TopStack* ts); //returns element from top of stack
//  simple parser function for RPN expressions that assumes numbers have only one digit

void parseRPN(char expr[], TopStack* st);

// empties the stack using the pop operation

void emptyStack(TopStack* ts);

// performs the operation defined by character op on the elements on top of stack

void performOp(TopStack* st, char op);
```

and finally the main.c file:

```
#include "defs.h"

int main()
{
    TopStack* tp;

    tp = initTOS(); // initialize the top of stack structure
    testStack(tp); // this function tests your stack
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing ts->num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pTemp` in the function `pop` is used while uninitialized. Using a value in uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration will invoke *undefined behavior*.

The line

```
Stack *pTemp;
```

should be

```
Stack *ptemp = ts->top;
```

Also you will have to initialize `pTopStack->num` to zero in `initTOS()`, or you will invoke *undefined behavior* again for using value in buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized.

Another note is that they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1):

A *big* and *major* problem is that when you allocate memory with `malloc`, it does not initialize the memory in any way. The contents of the memory is *indeterminate*.

That means when you allocate memory for `TopStack` in the `initTOS` function, the structures `top` pointer will most likely not be `NULL` as well as `num` not being zero. Then you start to use these values and you will have *undefined behavior*.

You should initialize the memory in `initTOS`. Either by using `calloc` instead, or explicitly setting each member.

You seem to have problems with other uninitialized variables and data elsewhere as well.